# Why does `git merge-base` prepares a hypothetical merge commit when more than 3 commits are supplied?

Tags: git

When executing `git merge-base A B C`, the command calculates the merge base for `A` and `M`, where `M` is the hypothesical merge commit of `B` and `C`. (refer: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_discussion)

Why does the merge-base command behaves this way?
I mean, I thought it is more sensible if the result were the merge-base of all the commits; I didn't know this behaviour and made an operational accident.

---

Now, I know that the "sensible" behaviour I mentioned is achievable by giving `--octopus` option, but I wondered why it is not the default behaviour.

Is there any reason or use case of the current default behaviour?